# Is a vector-valued function with components defined by real-valued random variables a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

My understanding is that an $\mathbb{R}^N$-valued random variable over the probability space  $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measurable function from $(\Omega, \Sigma) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for $\mathbb{R}^N$. Please let me know if this is wrong or incomplete.

---

Now let's say I have $N$ mutually independent real-valued random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_N$ over the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$. Now say I define the function $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ as follows:
\begin{align}
Y(\omega) = (X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), ..., X_N(\omega))
\end{align}

Is $Y$ a $\mathbb{R}^N$-valued random variable? If not, is there some other $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $Y$ is a measurable function from $(\Omega, \Sigma) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^N, \Sigma(\mathbb{R}^N))$

Comment: The Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R^n$ coincides with the sigma algebra generated by functions whose components are $\mathbb R$ valued random variables.